# Conditional Forwarding to an external doman causes Email Sending to that domain to fail

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2010

My company (@abc.com) is in the process of merging its operation with another one (@xyz.com) and both are Microsoft shops with Exchange 2010 SP3.
The 2 networks are linked by an IPSEC tunnel.

We set up DNS conditional forwarding on each side.
In @abc.com network, we conditionally forward all DNS @xyz.com hostname request to @xyz.com internal DNS Server
In @xyz.com network, we conditionally forward all DNS @abc.com hostname request to @abc.com internal DNS Server

We then allow TCP/UDP 53 to flow through the IPSEC tunnel.

After that, we found out that in @abc.com, when we try to send email to someone@xyz.com, the emails are all stuck in the queue viewer of the Edge server with no error code.

1) In @abc.com, I went to the Edge server, in EMC / Edge Transport / Properties / External DNS Lookups, the DNS servers are all valid external DNS servers.  I did NSLOOKUP on the Edge server and was able to resolve external @xyz.com nicely.

2) I turned on verbose for Protocol Logging of the Send Connectors but the SMTPSend file does not record anything stuck in the queue.

3) I have a feeling that the Edge Server disregards the External DNS lookups and go straight to the conditional forwarder to get this the internal MX record of @xyz.com instead.  Because internally @xyz does not have any MX record and so it was therefore stuck in the queue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the relevant Send Connector configured to use the DNS lookup settings on the transport server?

Comment: @joeqwerty, let me check when I get back to the office.  BTW, what is the difference between the two options: 1) use domain name system DNS MX records to route mail automatically 2) Use the External DNS lookup settings on the transport server?

Comment: @joeqwerty, I checked the send connector called "EdgeSync - Default-First-Site-Name to Internet", the first option is checked which says "use domain name system DNS MX records to route mail automatically (Enable Domain Security Mutual Auth TLS) which I don't really understand what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the link below for the solution

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/2b34183b-5069-4959-8bac-4e5ef05d32f6/dns-conditional-forwarding-and-email-stuck-in-queue-viewer?forum=exchange2010#e26d774d-7343-4fb2-92f1-37db3ecc4bf6

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

To satisfy your requirement, I suggest you that create a forest trust between xyz.com and abc.com and then create cross-forest send connectors.

More details about how to configure forest trust and cross-forest send connectors: [Create a one-way,outgoing,forest trust](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779840(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) & [Configure a cross-forest Send connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/configure-a-cross-forest-send-connector-exchange-2013-help)

Best regards,

Ivan Wang